# How can i show badge with count when notification received in react native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, badge, react-native-push-notification

How can i show badge with count when notification received in react native using react-native-push-notification library.

Tried with shortcut badger but its not working on all phones

Comment: have you found the answer? I have the same promblem

Answer (score 0):

You can show badge number using the setApplicationIconBadgeNumber function

```html
PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(10);
```